# VBA can't open a workbook that exists

Tags: excel, vba, while-loop

I have a loop in VBA that takes a file path from a list, attempts to open that file, and checks to see if that file has external links.  I have catches for if the file is corrupt, if it is password protected, and if you need to enable editing when the code initially opens the workbook.  The loop works until it gets to one particular file.  Whenever the code reaches it, it pauses for about 5 seconds and then closes the workbook that has the macro running in it.  I'm able to copy the file path and paste in the file explorer, so I know this particular workbook exists.  Here's the start of the loop, with the rest of the code being the error catches and what to do when the code detects external links. I've tried starting the macro at this file's index number (StartNum) on the list and going line-by-line, so I'm pretty sure the problem comes at this point.

'''

```
Do While StartNum <= EndNum
    'at this point in the loop, the activeworkbook is set to be the excel workbook running the macro
    ActiveWorkbook.Save

    'first error catch.  ActiveFilePath is the full file pathway of the workbook I'm trying to open
    On Error GoTo CorruptFile
    Workbooks.Open ActiveFilePath, UpdateLinks:=0, ReadOnly:=False, Password:=""
```

'''

Thanks!

Comment: So you say the file that contains the macro gets force closed without any message? That looks to me like a bug or corrupt file that get's not detected as corrupt or a macro in the file that you open that runs and closes Excel. Does it also happen if you turn off events `Application.EnableEvents = False`? If it still happens it must be a bug or corrupt file. Then try if you can open that file manually and save it as xlsb file once than go back to the original format. This might work or not.

Comment: Could be an error in your error-handling code.  There's really not much to go on here.

Comment: yes, the code tries for a few seconds and then the file that contains this code closes (by a run time error, maybe?).  I was thinking of adding a block that says:  IF the workbook.open function takes more than x seconds, THEN go to next iteration of the loop.  i'm not having much luck with finding a clock-function.  the file that the code is trying to open isn't corrupt, so i don't think the 'on error goto' line activates

Comment: Single-threaded, so your code will hang on the Open() call and you won't be able to break out of that after checking the time elapsed (or even be able to check the time elapsed). You will need to figure out the root cause of the problem. Does the problem workbook contain any code?  Any links/querytables/etc ?

Comment: no links, no VBA code, no queries, no tables.  the problem file is saved as Excel 97-2003.  ever hear of anything like that causing a glitch when running a newer version of Excel?

Comment: Did you try what I suggested? Can you open this workbook manually in Excel? Try that at first please, because if that fails too, then we don't need to search for an issue in the code. I assume it is an issue with that file, not a code related issue.

Comment: I added your 'Applications.EnableEvents = False' line, but it doesn't look like it solved the issue.  The file exists:  I'm able to copy the string from my file list, paste that directly into the file explorer, hit enter, and then the workbook opens up no problem.